# Dockerized Django application refuses connections

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My Django application that is running on Docker won't allow me to connect to it when I type `0.0.0.0:8000` or even my `docker-machine ip`.

The error shows as below:

> Safari can’t open the page “‎0.0.0.0:8000” because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again.

Also when I try `docker-machine ssh default` I then type `wget -qO- 127.0.0.1:8000` to see if the server will let me connect from within the `docker vm`, I get this **error response**:

> docker@default:~$ wget -qO- 127.0.0.1:8000
>   wget: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

# Copying requirements files for python modules
ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt

# Installing build deps for running images
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
  build-base postgresql-dev libffi-dev \
  && pip install -r requirements.txt \
  && find /usr/local \
      \( -type d -a -name test -o -name tests \) \
      -o \( -type f -a -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.pyo' \) \
      -exec rm -rf '{}' + \
  && runDeps="$( \
    scanelf --needed --nobanner --recursive /usr/local \
            | awk '{ gsub(/,/, "\nso:", $2); print "so:" $2 }' \
            | sort -u \
            | xargs -r apk info --installed \
            | sort -u \
)" \
&& apk add --virtual .rundeps $runDeps \
&& apk del .build-deps

# Copying application code for the docker container to persist
RUN mkdir /src
COPY src/ /src
WORKDIR /src

# uWSGI port opening
EXPOSE 8000

# DJANGO enviroment settings
RUN DATABASE_URL=none /usr/local/bin/python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

**docker ps**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
382f6202153d        dronerestapi_app    "python manage.py ru…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp      dronerestapi_app_1
db6e0145a5da        postgres:9.6        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   dronerestapi_db_1
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
db:
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: drone_db
        POSTGRES_USER: app_user
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: changeme
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports:
        - 5432:5432
    volumes:
        - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

app:
    environment:
        DATABASE_URL: postgres://app_user:changeme@drone_db
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - ./src/:/src
    ports:
        - 8000:8000
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
        - db
```

As you can see I expose all the ports so the only thing I can think is going wrong is a `Django Settings error`. **Settings bellow**

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for core project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'fqa*89n0thw=bjr1-)&)l%@k5--17mhndy@!98u0(!@1hynzox'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS =  '*'


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'drones',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
       },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'drone_db',
    'USER': 'app_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'changeme',
    'HOST': 'db',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


 # Password validation
 # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-   validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I have no clue what to do everything I try just leads me not being allowed to connect to the Django server, I can connect to the Postgres server just fine via GUI tools.

Comment: Where did you start the django server?

Comment: @StephenRauch I start Django server on the command argument in the docker-compose file `command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: Port 8000 is exposed on the host; can you access it at `127.0.0.1:8000` from the host machine?

Comment: I am not an expert, by any means, but I would suggest cranking the log level down and checking logs in the container.

Comment: @jschnurr I tried that and Safari just tells me: `Safari can’t open the page “‎0.0.0.0:8000” because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again.`

Comment: @StephenRauch I ran the log check and the terminal just exists, The Django container won't show any logs

Comment: why are you using the address `0.0.0.0:8000` on safary?, you should use `127.0.0.1:8000` instead

Comment: @Motakjuq Says the same thing as before it won't let me connect, also `0.0.0.0` just tells Django to accept connections from all hosts

Comment: @Red3nzo Not for this issue. But 0.0.0.0 does not mean accepting connections from all hosts, it means that Django server binds itself with all network interfaces you have on its running environment, i.e. lo(127.0.0.1), eth0(say 172.17.0.2) and so on.

Comment: Just adding my solution. In my docker file , I used this. And I worked fine with http://127.0.0.1:8888:

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]